# How to force an app chooser for video player?

Tags: android

I have [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX0l7.jpg) of downloaded encrypted files videos , but they cant be played by the default android player.. I Have created my own player for playing the encrypted video . So what I want is that when the user clicks the encrypted video , it pops "complete action with?"  then they choose the required player. what should I add to my player app to make this happen? Please help

I want my video player to appear on the list like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e8Tj.png)

Here is my next class for getting the path of the selected video , how do i get the path ? I want the player to play the exact selected video from my donwload.

```
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * A PlayActivity variant that plays an encrypted video.
 */
public class PlayActivity2 extends APlayActivity {

    @Override
    public Cipher getCipher() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        final Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("ARC4");    // NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec("BrianIsInTheKitchen".getBytes(), "ARC4"));   // InvalidKeyException
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPath() {



        return "THE SELECTED PATH OF THE ENCRYPTED VIDEO";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding this to your

> manifest.xml

for registering your activity as **video player**

```
<!-- Video player -->
    <activity android:name=".APlayActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="rtsp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: How do I get the path of the selected video so that it can start playing on the player. I want it to be returned from this method       public String getPath() {


       directory.
        return "THE SELECTED PATH OF THE ENCRYPTED VIDEO";
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an `intent-filter` that you can handle your video's file format so that your player `Activity` will be called to play the video when you invoke the share intent.
For example you can add something like this in your player `<activity>` in your `Mainfest.xml`:

```
<!-- This activity also handles "SEND" and "SEND_MULTIPLE" with media data -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Also check the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) under receiving implicit intents.

Comment: Now .. kindly how do I get the path of the selected video so that it can start playing on the player. I want it to be returned from this method public String getPath() { directory. return "THE SELECTED PATH OF THE ENCRYPTED

Comment: Where is the the file that you get from your list??